# Ember iterations: when to use #each User, #each user in controller, #each user in model, etc

Tags: ember.js

I'm confused on how I'm supposed to iterate through arrays of objects and when to use the different possibilities.

So far I've come across:

```
{{#each user in controller}}
{{#each user in model}}
{{#each user in users}}
{{#each User}}
```

And I've even switched some of them up a bit just to see if I could break it; for example both

```
{{#each user in controller}}
```

and

```
{{#each user in model}}
```

output the same code successfully. I was hoping someone knew a simple explanation on when to use each one and what the differences between them are. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses of the `{{#each}}` helper are equivalent:

```
{{#each user in controller}}
{{#each controller}}
{{#each user in model}}
{{#each model}}
{{#each user in content}}
{{#each content}}
// and a couple of other possible combination, depending on your setup
```

And since this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2709) you can also use simply `{{#each}}`.

The main difference though is how you access the properties and the items itself you are looping over.

Example using `user` as the accessor:

```
{{#each user in model}}
  {{user.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Example using `this`:

```
{{#each model}}
  {{this.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Example accessing the item properties directly:

```
 {{#each model}}
   {{name}}
 {{/each}}
```

Hope this makes things more clear.