# Difference Between controller and controller.content

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController and was using `{{#each item in controller}}` to iterate over the items in the controller. This was working fine while using the same controller however after switching to another route I ran into some weird behavior which stopped the items from being rerendered. Switching to `{{#each item in controller.content}}` solved this problem. However I am not sure how this even happened.

What's the difference between controller and controller.content in an each expression (or any where else).

Comment: Sorry but, I don't get the '... however after switching controllers ...', do you mean, transitioning between routes?

Comment: Yes, actually switchting to another route destroyed my binding. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the difference between controller and controller.content in an each expression (or any where else).

Basically there is no difference, for example when using an `ArrayController` which extends from `ArrayProxy`, then inside the controller `this.pushObject(obj)` will behave the same as doing `this.get('content').pushObject(obj)`. See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.7/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/array_proxy.js#L275) for reference.

But IMO you are better of using `model` everywhere e.g. `{{#each item in model}}`.
Check also this answer which I guess will be useful: [Ember iterations: when to use #each User, #each user in controller, #each user in model, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846274/ember-iterations-when-to-use-each-user-each-user-in-controller-each-user-i?rq=1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using `{{#each item in model}}` actually also fixes the problem I had and is much more readable than `controller`.

Comment: @cedric, don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question :) thanks